# Increment operator doesn't show expected result

Tags: apex

Let's say we have following

```
Integer a = 0;
a = a++;
System.debug(a)
```

why it shows 0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Incrementing modifies in place. You don't need to reassign at all. However, using the `++a` operator returns the value after increment, as opposed to the `a++` operator, which returns the value before increment.

Answer (score 8):

Speaking from a technical point of view, with the postfix operator, the compiler basically does this internally:

```
temp = a; // rvalue storage
a = a + 1; // ++ operator
a = temp; // lvalue assignment
```

As Adrian says, you shouldn't assign the value, as the prefix and postfix ++ and -- operators modify the variable being referenced.

Using a prefix operator (`a = ++a`) would change it to:

```
a = a + 1; // ++ operator
temp = a; // rvalue storage
a = temp; // lvalue assignment
```

You should generally not use a prefix or postfix operator on the variable being assigned to (the `lvalue`); in practice, the increment and decrement operators are typically used to modify an accumulator or counter, not modify the value currently being assigned to.